# Select2 from select with required not change border color.

Tags: select, jquery-select2, required

i have add in my form this css rule to add a border color orange if is required.

```
:required{
    border-color: #f8ac59 !important;
}
```

but this not work for Select2, when i try with this i add this individual:

```
.select2-selection{
    border-color: #f8ac59 !important;
}
```

the problem is that all select2 has the orange border, and i need only that the select2 from "select" Input with required attribute. how can i solve this.

HTML

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" data-width="100%" required>
    <option>Selec.</option>
    <option>Prueba 2 max with</option>
    <option>Prueba 3</option>
    <option>Prueba 4</option>
    <option>Prueba 5</option>
</select>
```

Initialice:

```
$('select').each(function () {
        $(this).off('change');
        var width= $(this).attr("data-width") || '100px';
        $(this).select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap4',
            placeholder: "Buscar y Selecionar",
            width: width,
            dropdownAutoWidth: true
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem it was necessary to make some changes in the scrip's iniaicalization:

```
$('select').each(function () {
        $(this).off('change');
        var width= $(this).attr("data-width") || '100px';
        $(this).select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap4',
            placeholder: "Buscar y Selecionar",
            width: width,
            dropdownAutoWidth: true
        });
        var x = this.required;
        if(x){
            $(this).next().children().children().each(function(){
                $(this).css( "border-color", "#f8ac59" );
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()" class="form-control form-control-sm" data-width="100%" required>
        <option value="one">Selec.</option>
        <option value="two">Prueba 2 max with</option>
        <option value="tree">Prueba 3</option>
        <option value="four">Prueba 4</option>
        <option value="five">Prueba 5</option>
    </select>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  if(x.value == "two"){
    x.style.border = "solid orange";
  }
  else{
    x.style.border = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the problem is that all select2 has the orange border, and i need only that the select2 from "select" Input with required attribute. how can i solve this in the select2

Comment: delete code from styles and then implement code I sent you

Comment: You don't need this .select2-selection{
    border-color: #f8ac59 !important;
} :required{
    border-color: #f8ac59 !important;
}